# react gives the error: setCount is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

receiving error of setcount is not a function.
i'm newbie please help me

```js
import React, { memo, useState } from "react";

export const Container = memo(function Container() {
    const { count, setCount } = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
    <button onClick={()=>setCount(count+1)}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: `useState` returns an array of two values not an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useState` doesn't return an object which you're destructuring.
It returns an array of two values i.e.  value and a function.

You should read [`React useState docs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

> It returns a pair of values: the current state and a function that
> updates it. This is why we write const [count, setCount] = useState().
> This is similar to this.state.count and this.setState in a class,
> except you get them in a pair. - REACT DOCS

Change

```js
const { count, setCount } = useState(0);
```

to

```js
 const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);
```

Comment: You should explain your solution atleast in a single line. How does your code help to solve OP problem.

Comment: You should also add links to the docs from where OP can read more about(If possible)

Answer (score 2):

replace the curly brackets with array brackets [] so it becomes

```js
const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);
```